# MySQL:(PHP) UPDATE Query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an UPDATE Query in MySQL

```
UPDATE users 
SET fname='$fname',lname='$lname',username='$user',password='$pass',role='$role',status=$status 
where id=$id
```

It works perfectly when I run it in `Phpmyadmin` by giving values manually but it gives me an error message when I use it in PHP Page.

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

The error is generated because I am doing echo `mysql_error()` I am getting values from the FORM like this;

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$fname=$_POST['txt_fname'];
$lname=$_POST['txt_lname'];
$user=$_POST['txt_user'];
$pass=$_POST['txt_pass'];
$role=$_POST['txt_role'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
```

Frankly I sound like a stupid asking such a simple question, but I am stuck and need a bit of help. Thanks

FORM HTML

```
<div id="cuntable" style=" width:400px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <form name="userform" action="updateuser.php" method="post">
    <table >
    <tr>    
        <td colspan="2"> Edit / Modify User Details </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt_fname" placeholder="<?php echo $row[1];?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt_lname" placeholder="<?php echo $row[2];?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt_user"  placeholder="<?php echo $row[3];?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="txt_pass"  placeholder="<?php echo $row[4];?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>
        <select name="txt_role">
            <option value=""> Select User Role </option>
            <option value="user"> User </option>
            <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
            <option value="operator">Operator</option>
            <option value="accountant">Accountant </option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Status </td>
        <td>
            <select name="status">
                <option value="1"> Active </option>
                <option value="0"> Suspended </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<br />
<input type="submit" value=" ADD USER " />
<input type="hidden" name="txt_id" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"
</form>
```

Comment: status=$status  to status='$status' and also post the form code in the question.

Comment: Is `$status` a string or an integer?

Comment: seems like your variables are not evaluate

Comment: $status is an integer

Comment: 3 things that would fail on your query:
empty or type mismatch in $id
`'` character on any of the other values
empty or type mismatch in $status

You might also use mysqli_real_escape_String() when values in a query are directly sent by users

Comment: Do not forget use http://cz2.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string or better yet PDO http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: http://uaedriving.com/dfs/admin.php?id=4 Check users in top navigation

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. I found my mistake. The hidden ID field in the form was named txt_id and I was trying to get it by only mentioning id hence I wasn't getting any ID at all. Thanks Olvathar, Thanks all others